# How to use the minify preset with babelify on babel 7?

Tags: javascript, browserify, babeljs, babelify

I installed the following packages:

```
npm install --save-dev babelify@next @babel/core @babel/preset-env babel-preset-minify
```

I can successfully browserify my NodeJS Express app with:

```
./node_modules/browserify/bin/cmd.js src/app.js -o src/bundle.js --node --exclude aws-sdk --transform [ babelify --presets [ "@babel/preset-env" ] ]
```

But if I try to add minify:

```
./node_modules/browserify/bin/cmd.js src/app.js -o src/bundle.js --node --exclude aws-sdk --transform [ babelify --presets [ "@babel/preset-env" , babel-preset-minify ] ]
```

I get:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'babel-preset-,' from '{projectDir}/' while parsing file: {projectDir}/src/bundle.js
...
```

The same happens if I change "babel-preset-minify" to just "minify".

What's missing here so I can minify my bundle.js?

Comment: I see missing quotation marks around babel-preset-minify. And I guess that you are mising uglify plugin..

Comment: The missing quotations are optional AFIK, and why would I be missing the uglify plugin?